# Do freeloaders have a detrimental impact on an economic system?

Tags: labor-economics

As far as I can tell, proponents of different systems of governance and taxation agree that freeloading is bad, even if they disagree on where the lines are (or ought to be) drawn. I'm not sure I agree.

If freeloaders are non-productive members of a system, who nevertheless rely on the output of productive members ("workers") for their basic needs, do they pose an *existential* threat to the system?

My naive view is that as long as the workers alone create enough to cover the needs of freeloaders + workers + a bit of insurance for disasters, the system is sustainable. Assuming all else is equal (and the workers aren't resentful) is this a valid stance?

Comment: I'm not familiar with economics, so any guidance on improving my question is welcome

Comment: By your definition children will be free-loaders. But children are important for survival of a country. From this would follow, that complete elimination of free loaders would be existentional threat to a society.

Comment: @user161005 good point, I had thought of elderly/infirm people and people who just-dont-wanna but not kids!

Comment: I feel this question is too vague. The best way I can interpret it is a political, not economic one, i.e. "if a system has many freeloaders, will the non-freeloaders feel obliged to overthrow the system?" Otherwise what is meant by an existential threat?

Comment: @user253751 by existential I mean that the system collapses because it cannot materially support itself (not because of an uprising)

Comment: @LeeMcGee I interpret that to mean the system results in too few goods and services being produced? But you have said that enough goods and services are produced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assumed everything that needs to be assumed in order for your question to be answered in the negative as a tautology.

The "workers are not resentful" part is the crucial assumption. Because otherwise, if we produce $100$ and we need $70$, the freeloaders need $20$ and $10$ is insurance, certainly the arithmetic checks by default.

*But is it sustainable over time?*

The first step to familiarize with economics, is to note that economics is not about money or production engineering, but about motives, goals, and behavior as regards economic matters.

Freeloading and getting away with it sets an example to be followed by others, given that most work activities are still a drag. But because things are never simple in economics, what matters is the degree and the extend of freeloading, not whether it exists or not.

So in principle, freeloading poses a possible existential threat on the economic system, depending on how much is allowed to spread. And we do not know whether a universal critical threshold exists.

Comment: ok, this helps me understand "economics" more too, I literally discovered yesterday that it is classed as a social science!

Comment: You should just say durable and perishable inventory, equipment, and even intellectual property, rent, and owner-imputed rent but never non-monetary research and open source content use to benefit technical growth (if dynamic-use growth is just substitutive to complementary luxury non-deflationary nor -equalizing with persistence through capital stock versus poverty disparity narrowing or once income).